# Ionic/Angluar NGX Datatable: Transform boolean values to string

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ngx-datatable

I am developing an Ionic/Angular application and I am using NGX datatable. It works pretty good, but I need to display the boolean values of one column not as "true" or "false" (English language) - I need to display the boolean values in German ("true" = "Ja" , "false" = "Nein").

The problem is that I am using the automatically generating columns, so my datatable in html looks like this:

```
<ngx-datatable [selectionType]="'single'" (select)="openDetailsPage($event)" [messages]="messages"
        class="bootstrap" [limit]="10" [rows]="allOpenTickets" [rowHeight]="50" [columns]="columns"
        [columnMode]="'force'" [sortType]="'multi'" [headerHeight]="50" [footerHeight]="50"
        [rowClass]="getRowClass">
</ngx-datatable>
```

And i define my columns in typescript like:

```
this.columns = [
    { name: 'Id', prop: 'id' },
    { name: 'Ziel', prop: 'goalDate', pipe: this.datePipe() },
    { name: 'Erstellt', prop: 'created' , pipe: this.datePipe() },
    { name: 'Titel', prop: 'title' },
    {name:'Erledigt',prop:'done'}
];
```

As you can see, I use a datetipe to transform the date, is there something like a pipe for boolean values? Or should I not use the automatically generated columns and instead create my own?

My final table should look like this:
[final table picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxBTC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any kind of pipe you desire to transform the data - even your custom pipe (as per docs [here](https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-datatable/api/column/inputs#pipe-pipetransform)). This is the signature of a [PipeTransform](https://angular.io/api/core/PipeTransform).

So you probably want something along the lines of:

```
germanBooleanPipe(): PipeTransform {
  return {
    transform: (value: boolean) => value ? "Ja" : "Nein";
}
```

And apply that pipe to  your column:

```
this.columns = [
    { name: 'Id', prop: 'id' },
    { name: 'Ziel', prop: 'goalDate', pipe: this.datePipe() },
    { name: 'Erstellt', prop: 'created' , pipe: this.datePipe() },
    { name: 'Titel', prop: 'title' },
    { name:'Erledigt', prop:'done', pipe: this.germanBooleanPipe() }
];
```

Note that I've never used `ngx-datatable` myself, so this might need some minor adjustments.